# Empty memory use by ftrace?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, ftrace

ftrace uses memory to keep the trace record. Before starting a new trace, the old traces are still kept in the memory by ftrace has to be emptied. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will empty it 'echo > '